# values folder for dimen.xml for small screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to set custom margins and textSize with respect to the screen size of the device. I have searched over the web, but did not find any answer of my need:

Where should I store the dimen values for smaller screen size, as in for mdpi screens.

Please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use dimen.xml for storing dimeansions in different resolution folders

Comment: yes, i know that. But what should be the name of the 'values' folder for small screens. I want the name.

Comment: that depends on which device u using

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit confused with the question. Not that I'm an expert but the size of the screen doesn't directly translate to pixel density. You are talking about small screens and then randomly refer to mdpi screens. So, just to be clear, you can have a device with what Android categorize as a small screen with a "normal" pixel density screen (mdpi) but you can also have a large screen with the same pixel density. So...

1. if you want to define custom dimensions for a "small" screen with normal pixel density. You can add a dimens.xml resource file inside a `values-small-mdpi` folder
2. if you only want to target mdpi screens, then add the dimens.xml file inside a `values-mdpi` folder
3. and lastly, if you want to target small screens only, then add it to a `values-small` resource folder

You have a lot resource folder qualifiers to choose from...so be careful you don't bloat your project with a lot of these files. The link below explains how you can use them, the order of the qualifiers and precedence...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Furthermore, in regards to text sizes, you don't usually have to worry about the pixel density of the screen...you would, if you were rendering a background image. For text sizes, you'll need to make sure you specify scale-independent units (sp)...that's all you need to worry about.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a perfect answer. My answer is in point number 3.

Comment: I put `dimens` in `values-small` and it doesn't work

Comment: @david sure it does mate. Since API Level 4. Make sure you read the docs and understand what you read

Comment: @Leo yes sorry about that, I read other issue that `sw320dp` which cascades to all values I thought this answer contradicts it but after reading the order of precedence then I realise that this answer is a different purpose, So i think your answer is correct.